# Deleting multiple image files with specific criteria

Tags: script, images, automation, code

I'm looking for an easy way to delete images in my Wallpapers folder with dimensions less than 1080x1920. I thought there might be some kind of script/command that could do this. I once ran into a scripting function in Windows itself, but I really didn't understand much of it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can use the open-source `exiftool` to extract the dimensions: `exiftool -ImageSize ImageFilePath`. The result can then be parsed into the horizontal and vertical dimensions, which can be compared with the deletion criteria.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You don't even provide your operating system or make any attempt to write a script yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is using the **exiftool**. [Download it](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) (be sure to grab the Windows Executable, not the Linux file listed at first). Open an editor, paste the following code and save it as "deletesmallwp.bat" (or change the "filename" value accordingly)

```vbs
@echo off
REM SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Writes all img filenames smaller 1920/1080px for either a given parameter or a predefined folder into a txt file, then reads it and deletes all files written in there.
REM Without -r, not recursive, so without sub-folders.
REM "exifpath" needs to be changed to the path of the exiftool and "picpath" to the path of the pictures to be checked and deleted.
REM No need to run as admin, as long as you have the proper file permissions to delete (change)

ECHO Parameter: %1 

REM Paths can be either absolute or relative to the folder of this batch file. See f.e. exifpath 
REM In this ex. the batch is saved in "Pictures" and the pics to delete are in "Pictures\Wallpapers"
set exifpath=C:\Users\User\Pictures\exif\exiftool.exe
set exifpath=exif\exiftool.exe
set picpath=Wallpapers
set exportfile=smallwp.txt
set filename=deletesmallwp

REM Check from where file was run and set working directory if needed.
set batchpath=%0
set res=
IF %batchpath% == %filename% set res=1
IF "%batchpath%" == "%filename%.bat" set res=1
IF NOT DEFINED res (
    cd /D %~dp0
)

REM Check if file exists, else skip to the end
IF NOT EXIST %exifpath% GOTO NOPORT

REM Some info
IF [%1] EQU [] ( ECHO UNDEFINED)

ECHO.
IF NOT DEFINED res ECHO INFO: Changed working directory
ECHO.

REM Check if a parameter is given, then run exiftool to create a list with images
IF [%1] EQU [] (
    ECHO -Direct: '%picpath%'
    %exifpath% -if "$imagesize and ($imagewidth<1920 or $imageheight<1080)" -filename -T -L %picpath% >%exportfile%
) ELSE (
    ECHO -Parameter 'see above'
    %exifpath% -if "$imagesize and ($imagewidth<1920 or $imageheight<1080)" -filename -T -L %1 >%exportfile%
)
ECHO.
ECHO If you don't want certain files to be deleted, now might be a good time to look into %exportfile%.
ECHO.
pause
ECHO.
REM REM Delete every file found in the file and print the success
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%exportfile%) do del "%picpath%\%%A" 2>&1 >nul|findstr "^" >nul && echo FAILURE with %%A || echo DELETED
ECHO.
goto :ENDE

:NOPORT
echo "Portable ExifTool missing"
goto :ENDE


:ENDE
pause
```

Change set values according to the first comment lines (REM). Then run it (either from explorer or from command prompt (with the picture folder as parameter)). Hope this is what you've been looking for/the code is easy enough to understand. If you need any further help, best add a comment to your question.

Comment: I was wondering - since we talk about wallpapers - what happens when the user has pivot-able monitor (and makes use of it). Sadly by default windows just stretches the image. But with UltraMon & Co this changes so you might want s.t. like this (untested) `(($imagewidth<1920 and $imageheight<1080) or ($imagewidth<1080 and $imageheight<1920))`